# Returning a reference to a pointer from a function same as returning a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, reference

I have a feeling that the two examples in the following are equivalent, that is, returning a reference to a pointer and returning a pointer are the same thing. It sounds strange to say this, that a reference to pointer and pointer are the same thing, but I think it is the case in this example:

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct Animal{};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Animal*> map;

Animal* createNewMapEntry()
{
    return map["new entry"] = new Animal; // map subscript operator will return a reference to the mapped type
                                        // in this case the mapped type is a pointer to Animal
    // Is this the equivalent of doing:
    auto p = new Animal;
    map["new entry"] = p;
    return p;
    // In this case I am returning a pointer to Animal, not a reference to the pointer to animal.
    // That's why I was afraid that in the first example, which returns a "reference" to the Animal pointer
    // that it was returning the "address" of the pointer instead of the pointer, equivalent to returning 
    // a pointer to pointer, which is just like the address to a pointer.
}
```

If this is true, I think this is a really confusing part of the language, at least for me.

Comment: The first version inserts into the map and the second one doesn't, so they are not equivlaent

Comment: It's not the maps subscript operator that is used in the `return` statement, but the result of the *assignment*. Which is the pointer you just created.

Comment: I know the second doesn't insert into the map, I mean specifically about the return types, one returns reference to pointer and the second returns pointer, I should change my question

Comment: If a function returns by value and you return an lvalue, the lvalue is converted to prvalue ,  so the return statement just returns the pointer

Comment: I've changed the question for both cases to insert into the map, but my question is specifically about the return type, one being reference to pointer, and the other being pointer

Comment: If you had `int f() { int x = 0; int& y = x; ...}`, do you think there would be a difference between `return x;` and `return y;`?

Comment: @molbdnilo ohh, I think I see. You don't return the reference to x, you return x, even though you're returning y, which is a reference to x, haha. I guess it's some sort of conversion it does...?

Comment: @Zebrafish There's not really any conversion. You can consider `x` and `y` as synonyms.

Comment: The function returns a pointer to an `Animal` by value, period. Whatever you tell it to return will be converted to that.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a feeling that the two examples in the following are equivalent.

*No*, they are not.

The first inserts to the map, with key "new entry" and value an `Animal` object.

The second one doesn't do this, since it just returns the pointer.

---

As MM said: "If a function returns by value and you return an lvalue, the lvalue is converted to prvalue , so the return statement just returns the pointer".

Comment: I've changed the question, I know the second doesn't insert, I was wondering about the return types, one being reference to pointer, the other being pointer

Comment: @Zebrafish I updated the answer, hope that helps. Thanks for the upvote, I upvoted it too!

Comment: "A prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue." An xvalue is an expiring value, so you're saying that p here is an rvalue? I know it's temporary within that function block.

Comment: @Zebrafish `p` is an lvalue. Rule of thumb: If it has a name, then it is an lvalue. MM, and gsamaras are saying that the lvalue (whether it is an lvalue reference or a variable identifier) is converted into a prvalue that is the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the compound statement that is the function body have no effect on the return type of the function (unless the return type is `auto`).

The return type is `Animal*`, which is not a reference type. The examples are semantically equivalent.

Comment: The thing is that it says map[] returns a reference to the mapped type, and the mapped type is a pointer to Animal, so I took that to mean it returns a reference to Animal pointer. In the second example I return a pointer. So if I return a pointer or reference to pointer it does the same thing, that's what confused me. So I guess after map[] returns the reference it does some sort of conversion from reference to pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Zebrafish the subscript operator does return a reference. But whatever the subscript operator returns has no effect on what the function `createNewMapEntry` returns. `createNewMapEntry` does not return a reference.

Comment: @Zebrafish when people say "return a reference" they mean that the return type is declared as a reference;  but when you call the function in an expression what actually happens is the return value is an lvalue that designates some pre-existing object.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of `T&` to `T` in expressions is a fundamental aspect of C++. It's one of the first things that happens during expression evaluation.
See [[expr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#5):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” ([dcl.ref],
>   [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further
>   analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by
>   the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending
>   on the expression.

Since the result of `map["new entry"]` is `Animal*&` (and the assignment expression returns an [lvalue referring to the left operand](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1)), the `&` in the `return` expression disappears, leaving an *lvalue* `Animal*`. After that, since the expected return type of `createNewMapEntry()` is `Animal*`, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion takes place and a *copy* of the pointer is returned.

Note - the return type is always `Animal*` as declared, you never "*return a reference*" in this example. In both cases *a pointer* is returned.

Comment: The expression in the `return` statement is the result of built-in assignment operator, not the result of the map  lookup.

Comment: @M.M - the assignment expression returns an [lvalue referring to the left operand](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1), which is the result of `std::map::operator[]`.

Comment: The lvalue refers to a memory location, not to something that refers to a memory location (if you see what I'm getting at) ... this is all tautological once OP understands what lvalues are

Comment: Exactly, `Animal*&` in expressions unwraps into an "lvalue `Animal*`", it's the same thing. But an lvalue does not have to refer to *memory* as in DRAM, per se.